# How web server sends a file to a client

Tags: http

I am trying to create a web server which has some clients, the webserver has some users(unregistered) which request some files and web server should send the requested file to users. Now my question is how the web server should send back the file? I do not want to make it like a ftp server, so should I create a socket and send file? what are other web servers doing to send the file?

Answer (score 3):

The server will have to listen on some interface. Clients will start the process and connect to the server by opening a socket and request some content. On the same connection the server will respond with the requested content or an error.

Clients (usually browsers) communicate with Web servers using HTTP. At http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt you can find the description of the protocol. For basic stuff it is quite simple.

Not much changes if the client asks for an HTML file (a web page) or some other file. In the header of the server's response (the first part sent), the client will find some information about the type of content, so that he knows how to display it. The header is followed by the actual data (file or some program generated data).

Hope this helps